# String formatting without index in python2.6

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-2.6, backport

I've got many thousands of lines of python code that has python2.7+ style string formatting (e.g. without indices in the `{}`s)

```
"{} {}".format('foo', 'bar')
```

I need to run this code under python2.6 which *requires* the indices.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a painless way allow python2.6 to run this code. It'd be great if there was a `from __future__ import blah` solution to the problem. I don't see one. Something along those lines would be my first choice.

A distant second would be some script that can automate the process of adding the indices, at least in the obvious cases:

```
"{0} {1}".format('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: Might not be an actual solution, but one could try to monkey-patch a `format` method on `str` that does a nasty replacement of `{}` with `{index}` and then calls the 'real' `format` with the added indices.

Comment: @akaIDIOT: I don't think that will work for two reasons.  First, `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'`.  Second, that wouldn't affect string literals, which don't actually call `str`.

Comment: Can you install Python 2.7 on the machine? There are Python distributions which will can install and run without root permissions...

Comment: any possible reason for using a outdated version of python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't quite preserve the whitespacing and could probably be made a bit smarter, but it will at least identify Python strings (apostrophes/quotes/multi line) correctly without resorting to a regex or external parser:

```
import tokenize
from itertools import count
import re

with open('your_file') as fin:
    output = []
    tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(fin.readline)
    for num, val in (token[:2] for token in tokens):
        if num == tokenize.STRING:
            val = re.sub('{}', lambda L, c=count(): '{{{0}}}'.format(next(c)), val)
        output.append((num, val))

print tokenize.untokenize(output) # write to file instead...
```

Example input:

```
s = "{} {}".format('foo', 'bar')
if something:
    do_something('{} {} {}'.format(1, 2, 3))
```

Example output (note slightly iffy whitespacing):

```
s ="{0} {1}".format ('foo','bar')
if something :
    do_something ('{0} {1} {2}'.format (1 ,2 ,3 ))
```

Comment: Thanks all. I have no choice but to maintain 2.6 compatibility. Otherwise I'd require an upgrade. tokenize is definitely the magic I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to re-format your format strings:

```
def reformat(s):
    return "".join("".join((x, str(i), "}")) 
                   for i, x in list(enumerate(s.split("}")))[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good old sed-regex like:

```
sed source.py -e 's/{}/%s/g; s/\.format(/ % (/'
```

your example would get changed to something like:

```
"%s %s" % ('foo', 'bar')
```

Granted you loose the fancy new style `.format()` but imho it's almost never useful for trivial value insertions.

Answer (score 0):

A conversion script could be pretty simple. You can find strings to replace with regex:

```
fmt = "['\"][^'\"]*{}.*?['\"]\.format"

str1 = "x; '{} {}'.format(['foo', 'bar'])"
str2 = "This is a function; 'First is {}, second is {}'.format(['x1', 'x2']); some more code"
str3 = 'This doesn't have anything but a format. format(x)'
str4 = "This has an old-style format; '{0} {1}'.format(['some', 'list'])"
str5 = "'{0}'.format(1); '{} {}'.format(['x', 'y'])"

def add_format_indices(instr):
    text = instr.group(0)
    i = 0
    while '{}' in text:
        text = text.replace('{}', '{%d}'%i, 1)
        i = i+1
    return text

def reformat_text(text):
    return re.sub(fmt, add_format_indices, text)

reformat_text(str1)
"x; '{0} {1}'.format(['foo', 'bar'])"
reformat_text(str2)
"This is a function; 'First is {0}, second is {1}'.format(['x1', 'x2']); some more code"
reformat_text(str3)
"This doesn't have anything but a format. format(x)"
reformat_text(str4)
"This has an old-style format; '{0} {1}'.format(['some', 'list'])"
reformat_text(str5)
"'{0}'.format(1); '{0} {1}'.format(['x', 'y'])"
```

I think you could throw a whole file through this. You can probably find a faster implementation of add_format_indices, and obviously it hasn't been tested a whole lot.

Too bad there isn't an `import __past__`, but in general that's not something usually offered (see the 2to3 script for an example), so this is probably your next best option.